# Language as param in Vue Router

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-router

I would like to have a language param in my path. For example if there is `en` before the path, print `en`.

If I enter `http://localhost:8080/en` it will give me `en` but if I enter `http://localhost:8080/en/aaaa` it will return me `undefined`
how can I get `en` anyway?

```
const routes = [
  {
    path: "/:lang?",
    children: [
      {
        path: home,
        component: home
      }
    ]
  }
]
router.beforeEach((to, _, next) => {
  console.log(to.params.lang);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Under the assumption that you are planning on adding different language support for your app, I would recommend instead using [i18n](https://kazupon.github.io/vue-i18n/guide/locale.html) because it will abstract away things like appending params for different languages.

To your specific question on why you are getting `undefined`, that could simply be because there is no view page or route for the `/aaa` route. So Vue is just confused on where you want to go.

Answer (score 2):

You can use pure javascript to get the current url and get the parameters through a split.

```
let myListParams = window.location.href.split('/');
```